# Images not rendering in new iOS 16 Widgets?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widgetkit, ios16, xcode14

I'm working on a new .accessoryInline widget, introduces with iOS 16. It's very simple, only displays static text and an image, said image is a custom SF Symbol, validated and also used in other places in which it works just fine (for example a .accessoryRectangular widget). Here is my code:

```
case .accessoryInline:
            HStack {
                Image("mysymbol.car")
                  .resizable()
                  .widgetAccentable()
                Text("My Static Title")
            }
```

This however only renders the text when running the app and leaves a weird small space where the image should be. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: What fixed it for me was moving the lockscreen widgets code from its own target to a shared target with the homescreen widgets and used `WidgetBundle`

Answer (score 4):

On iOS 17 accessoryInline widgets do not show the image, this works for me:

change

```objectivec
Image("xxx")
```

to

```objectivec
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "xxx") ?? UIImage())
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing this issue as well. Apparently there are size limits for inline widget icons. Resizable doesn't work, so the file itself has a size limit. There is no documentation on this anywhere, so I do not have the numbers yet.

Update: Using a PNG of size 145x145 seems to do the trick.

Comment: If I use a png, the widget isn't rendered at all and only the loading blocks are shown unfortunately

Comment: Couple things to check: Does PNG have background transparency? Is the size 145x145 or smaller?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `Label` to render image with text. HStack will not work there.

```
Label {
    Text("My Static Title")
        .foregroundColor(.white)
} icon: {
    Image("mysymbol.car")
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 12, height: 21, alignment: .center)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but while this is a much cleaner way, it still didn't make it work, weirdly enough, it works on the simulator and preview where hstack did too

Comment: @Dave19 Can you please share your whole code including entry view?

Answer (score 0):

Draw your symbol on a `.png`-file, include that in your widget's bundle, and load the image through this `.png`-file.

I can assure you that loading a `.png`-file does work for me. There might be another issue that it doesn't work for you as you mentioned in a comment to @swiftyboi's answer.

`.inlineAccessory` is selective on images. I found that it does load SFSymbol images (through `Image(systemName: String)`) as well as bundle images in some but not all formats. However, it ignores images drawn with `Path`, so it does not surprise me that it also ignores custom symbols.

It also seems to ignore all formatting information. It just uses the first image and the first text it finds and displays them in this order.